# convert timestamp to day of the week android

Tags: android, kotlin, timestamp

I am trying to convert a timestamp to a day of the week.

The goal would be to translate to something like ts -> MON or TUE ....

I have tried the code below but it's not working.

```
fun convertToReadableDate(timestamp: Long): String {
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy")
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)
    cal.timeInMillis = timestamp * 1000
    val date: LocalDate = LocalDate.parse(formatter.format(cal.time))
    return date.dayOfWeek.toString()
}
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format in Kotlin date in string or timestamp to my preferred format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57402045/how-to-format-in-kotlin-date-in-string-or-timestamp-to-my-preferred-format)

Comment: can you share your timestamp format?

Comment: @NitinPrakash it's  `Unix, UTC` - 1618308000 . I have the timezone as well

Comment: can you please check my answer and mark it correct if it is fine???

Comment: @Seb if you got your answer please mark it and if not please write issue in the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. get the day of the week from Unix timestamp:-

   ```
    fun getDayOfWeek(timestamp: Long): String {
    return SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(timestamp * 1000)
   ```

   }
2. getMonth:

   ```
    fun getMonthFromTimeStamp(timestamp: Long): String {
    return SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.ENGLISH).format(timestamp * 1000)
   ```

   }
3. getYear:

   ```
    fun getYearFromTimeStamp(timestamp: Long): String {
    return SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(timestamp * 1000)
   ```

   }
4. if you need all three combined in one function: (WED-MAY-2021)

   ```
    fun getDayOfWeek(timestamp: Long): String {
        return SimpleDateFormat("EEEE-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(timestamp * 1000)
    }
   ```
5. if you need a combination of either of two in one function:(WED-MAY)

   ```
    fun getDayOfWeek(timestamp: Long): String {
        return SimpleDateFormat("EEEE-MMM", Locale.ENGLISH).format(timestamp * 1000)
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formatter:

```
fun convertToReadableDate(timestamp: Long): String = 
        SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(timestamp)
       .toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)
```